# How to format a string with a value from resources and one value from Binding in XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I need to develop an application that supports localization, so I need to format a `TextBlock` in such a way that part of the string takes one parameter from binding and part from a resources. I have written like this

```
<TextBlock Height="30" >
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0} -- *Now only* {1:C}!">
            <Binding Path="Description"/>
            <Binding Path="Price"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

this *Now Only* part I need to fetch from resource string. The string is there in the resources but I don't know how to fromat the string in such a fashion. Can anyone help me please.

I know that using a converter would be a solution, but I have many such scenarios and for that I may end up with a multiple converters which is not a good idea. I believe that using a `StringFormat` I can achieve it.  But I am missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a reference to your Resources namespace then add another Binding to you MultiBinding

Example (untested)

```
   xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Properties"

   <TextBlock Height="30" >
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0} -- {2} {1:C}!">
                <Binding Path="Description"/>
                <Binding Path="Price"/>

                <Binding Path="{x:Static p:Resources.Nowonly}"/>
                <!-- Or possibly Source instaed of Path as mentioned by @dkozl -->
                <Binding Source="{x:Static p:Resources.Nowonly}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

Comment: I already tried this but I am getting exception StringFormatExamples.Properties.Resources.Nowonly' StaticExtension value cannot be resolved to an enumeration, static field, or static property. Its failing

Comment: try `{Binding Source="{x:Static p:Resources.Nowonly}`. Notice `Source` instead of `Path`

Comment: Yeah I cant really test right now (on my phone, sorry) but you can bind to your resources, so its just a matter of setting the binding, @dkozi suggestion may work

Comment: OK it seems I found a solution it should be `<Binding Source="{x:Static resx:Resources.Nowonly}"/>`

Comment: @dkozl thanks for the help, But let me ask you is there any other way I can achieve this. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: However source is also throwing the same exception

Comment: is the `resx` xmlns path to your resources correct?

Comment: this is the value `xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:StringFormatExamples.Properties"`

Comment: Is it possible to use Mutlibinding as static resource and reference it in another multibinding ? with string format ? I have two multibindings but one is a subset of another and i don't want to repeat same xaml in two places just wondering if it's possible

Answer (score 1):

OK Finally I found a solution, but I believe that there may be many solutions to this. This is the first one.

As pointed out by @sa_ddam213 and @dkozl, that adding a `Source` instead of `Path` like:

```
<Binding Source="{x:Static p:Resources.Nowonly}"/>
```

is a perfect solution, but after that I was still getting a runtime exception

> 'StringFormatExamples.Properties.Resources.Nowonly'
>   StaticExtension value cannot be resolved to an enumeration, static field, or static property.

After working with the code for sometimes I figured out that in the access modifiers for all the resource strings is `internal`, I changed that into `public` and the code is working.